# Mongobooster aggregate function running error

Tags: javascript

when i am trying to run the query using aggregate function in mongobooster on windows 7 32 bit pc...its giving me this error..please help me to resolve this error...

```
"message" : "not authorized on strict to execute command { aggregate: 'PermanentBookings', pipeline: [ { $match: { $or: [ { city: 'Torino' } ], init_date: { $gte: new Date(1506816000000), $lte: new Date(1509494399000) } } }, { $project: { _id: 0.0, moved: { $ne: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ '$origin_destination.coordinates', 0.0 ] }, { $arrayElemAt: [ '$origin_destination.coordinates', 1.0 ] } ] }, duration: { $devide: [ { $subtract: [ '$final_time', '$init_time' ] }, 60.0 ] }, hourDay: { $hour: '$init_date' }, day: { $dayOfMonth: '$init_date' } } }, { $match: { moved: true, duration: { $lte: 180.0, $gt: 2.0 } } }, { $sort: { day: 1.0, hourDay: 1.0 } }, { $skip: 0.0 } ], cursor: {} }",
    "stack" : "MongoError: not authorized on strict to execute command { aggregate: 'PermanentBookings', pipeline: [ { $match: { $or: [ { city: 'Torino' } ], init_date: { $gte: new Date(1506816000000), $lte: new Date(1509494399000) } } }, { $project: { _id: 0.0, moved: { $ne: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ '$origin_destination.coordinates', 0.0 ] }, { $arrayElemAt: [ '$origin_destination.coordinates', 1.0 ] } ] }, duration: { $devide: [ { $subtract: [ '$final_time', '$init_time' ] }, 60.0 ] }, hourDay: { $hour: '$init_date' }, day: { $dayOfMonth: '$init_date' } } }, { $match: { moved: true, duration: { $lte: 180.0, $gt: 2.0 } } }, { $sort: { day: 1.0, hourDay: 1.0 } }, { $skip: 0.0 } ], cursor: {} }" +
              "at Function.MongoError.create (C:\\Users\\Pinky\\AppData\\Local\\mongobooster\\app-3.5.7\\resources\\app.asar\\node_modules\\mongodb-core\\lib\\error.js:31:11)" +
              "at queryCallback (C:\\Users\\Pinky\\AppData\\Local\\mongobooster\\app-3.5.7\\resources\\app.asar\\node_modules\\mongodb-core\\lib\\cursor.js:212:36)" +
              "at C:\\Users\\Pinky\\AppData\\Local\\mongobooster\\app-3.5.7\\resources\\app.asar\\node_modules\\mongodb-core\\lib\\connection\\pool.js:469:18" +
              "at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)" +
              "at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)",
    "name" : "MongoError",
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on strict to execute command { aggregate: 'PermanentBookings', pipeline: [ { $match: { $or: [ { city: 'Torino' } ], init_date: { $gte: new Date(1506816000000), $lte: new Date(1509494399000) } } }, { $project: { _id: 0.0, moved: { $ne: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ '$origin_destination.coordinates', 0.0 ] }, { $arrayElemAt: [ '$origin_destination.coordinates', 1.0 ] } ] }, duration: { $devide: [ { $subtract: [ '$final_time', '$init_time' ] }, 60.0 ] }, hourDay: { $hour: '$init_date' }, day: { $dayOfMonth: '$init_date' } } }, { $match: { moved: true, duration: { $lte: 180.0, $gt: 2.0 } } }, { $sort: { day: 1.0, hourDay: 1.0 } }, { $skip: 0.0 } ], cursor: {} }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
}
```